# Motorola XT910 reads rssi equal to 0 from bluetooth low energy tags ticc2540,ticc2541,blue radios tags

Tags: bluetooth, motorola, rssi, energy

I develop an Android application running on Motorola RAZR XT910 with OS version 4.0.4.

This application uses the Motorola_ICS_R2_sdkaddon_100   BluetoothGattService.jar and BluetoothGatt.jar libraries and communicates with Bluetooth
Low Energy Sensor Tags (TI CC2540,TI CC2541,Blue Radios Sensor Tags).

On Discovery procedure I always read the rssi value equal to 0 . I use the following code
to read the rssi value on receiving the Intent BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:

short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,(short) 0);

Also for non Bluetooth low energy devices,the rssi value i read is ok (not equal to 0).

Can anyone help me??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue on the TI discussion site for using the Vender Specific query for RSSI. It seems that it works for Classic BT but returns an error code of 2 for BLE.

http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/660/t/289391.aspx

It might be a fundamental limit that you can't get the value. In your case, the `getShortExtra` might not return the error code (2) and just return a 0 as RSSI.